# django custome login redirection middleware redirection problem says ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: django, middleware

hi friends i need some help i want to redirect a user when he try to access a page in my django

**settings.py** is

MIDDLEWARE = ['cart.middleware.LoginRedirectMiddleware']

**url.py** is (home is the app name)

```
path('',views.login,name="login"),
path('home',views.home,name="home"),
```

**middleware.py** is (located in mainapp)

```
def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
    """
    Called just before Django calls the view.
    """
    print("executed")
    if (request.user.is_authenticated):
       return redirect('home')
    else:
        return redirect('login')
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error is because your middleware only redirects the user in either outcome of the if-statement - so your code is constantly redirecting, even if they are taken to the home page - hence the `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error.

What you need to do is specify that you want to redirect to 'home' if the user is authenticated AND trying to access the login page.

```
if (request.user.is_authenticated and request.path == '/login/'):
   return redirect('home')
else:
   return redirect('login')
```

Your actual request.path might look different, something like `/accounts/login/` is also common.

Answer (score -1):

1. I guess you have params in views.login / views.home?
   If so, you should add args or kwargs in the back of redirect?
   `redirect('home', *args, **kwargs)`
2. Use `return redirect('/some/url/')` instead of `return redirect('home')`

Ref:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Hope this could help

Comment: hi i dont understand it because i am new to django can you help me out what i need to exactly put in redirect

Comment: Using redirect with URL names is fine as it can use `reverse()`, the question was why too many redirects are happening which was due to a logic issue